# How can I shorten a clause that shares a structure similar to the clause that comes before?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, clauses, conjunction-reduction

I would like to know how I can shorten the second clause in the following situation

> Paris is the capital of France and Rome is the capital of Italy.

I do not want to duplicate the part `is the capital of`.

How can I shorten in this type of situation?

Comment: ...and Rome of Italy. (or 'and Rome that of Italy').

Comment: @KateBunting thanks alot! Do you have any source where I can learn more about this kind of shortening? Or what is this shortening called so I can google it?

Comment: Look up ellipsis, and [reduced relative clauses](https://www.thoughtco.com/reduced-relative-clauses-1211107#:~:text=Reduced%20relative%20clauses%20refer%20to,the%20subject%20of%20a%20sentence.&text=Much%20like%20adjectives%2C%20relative%20clauses,at%20Costco%20lives%20in%20Seattle).